# Different ways to say "at least" / 「少なくとも」

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I would like to know if there are other ways to say "at least~" (context below), along with the relevant nuances of each way.

This is for a piece of writing I'm doing where for the sake of style I want to avoid using the same phrase too many times. That said, please do include answers that may only be suitable for speech or conversation.

I am referring to "at least~" as used in the following context:

> It looks like I won't be able to return to Japan for **at least** 6 months
>   **少なくとも**６ヶ月の間日本に帰れないみたいです。

(in other words I'm not looking for answers referring to phrases like せめて〜, which translates to a different meaning of the English phrase "at least")

Comment: Just as in English, we would consult a thesaurus, in Japanese, you can consult a [類語辞典](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%EF%BD%9E).

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for the link. I wouldn't normally think to use a thesaurus for what is more of a grammar question about the nuance of phrases.

Comment: related [is there any difference between せめて and 少なくとも?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28482/is-there-any-difference-between-%E3%81%9B%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6-and-%E5%B0%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 最短で "for the shortest"
- 少なく見積もって "under the least/shortest estimate"
- は as in 六か月は

Comment: Also, `以上`, for example `6ヶ月以上`.

Comment: @Jesse I could be wrong, but the nuance of 以上 seems different, like "for more than 6 months" rather than "at least 6 months", so not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ジョン It does not mean more than six months. It means six months or more, which is the same as at least six months, distegarding the implication.

Comment: @sawa Sorry for the confusion. The implication you mention is what I was referring to in my comment, but I see that I phrased it poorly. That's why 以上 seems less suitable to me than the examples in your answer. For future reference am I correct in thinking this or am I making a mistake?

Comment: @ジョン I agree with you about the implication. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "最低（さいてい:lowest）６ヶ月".